# Filter branches by regex in GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I've got an XY-problem and I know it:

- X: I want to use GitKraken to filter branches so only `master` and branches where the name starts with `MY-` will be shown, all other branches should be filtered.
- Y: I want to use a regex to filter branches in GitKraken

For example in this list of branches:

```
master
some-silly-name
MY-123-good-branch
MY-55-other-branch
TH-777-branch-name
TH-1-first-branch
wip/some-wip-branch
wip/MY-66-branch
```

I would at least love to select:

- `master`
- `MY-123-good-branch`
- `MY-55-other-branch`

And as a nice to have also:

- `wip/MY-66-branch`

I can [do this with `(^(wip\/)?MY-.*)|master`](https://regex101.com/r/udQoYf/1), but GitKraken doesn't pick that up.

Is there any way I can use regexes in GitKraken's filter, or, failing that, any way to filter both master and branches with a specific filter?